# Why is my GAN not producing more good images after a certain point?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras, generative-adversarial-network

### Question

I was training a gan to generate human faces. Within approximately 500 epochs, it learned to generate images like this:

[image]

Well, now this image is not too bad. We can see a face in the center of the image.

Then I trained it for more 1000 epochs and it learned nothing. It was still generating the same type of images as shown above. Why was that? Why wasn't my gan not learning to produce even better images?

### Code for the Models

Here is the code of the discriminator:

```
    def define_discriminator(in_shape=(64, 64, 3)):
        Model = Sequential([
                Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=in_shape),
                BatchNormalization(),
                LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                Dropout(0.2),

                Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same'),
                BatchNormalization(),
                LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                Dropout(0.3),

                Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same'),
                BatchNormalization(),
                LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                Dropout(0.3),

                Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same'),
                BatchNormalization(),
                LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                Dropout(0.4),

                Flatten(),

                Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
        opt = Adam(lr=0.00002)
        Model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

        return Model
```

Here is the code of the generator and the GAN:

```
def define_generator(in_shape=100):
    Model = Sequential([
                Dense(256*8*8, input_dim=in_shape),
                BatchNormalization(),
                LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
                Reshape((8, 8, 256)),

                Conv2DTranspose(256, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same'),
                BatchNormalization(),
                LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),

                Conv2DTranspose(64, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same'),
                BatchNormalization(),
                LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),

                Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    return Model

def define_gan(d_model, g_model):
    d_model.trainable = False
    model = Sequential([
                g_model,
                d_model
    ])
    opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
    return model
```

### Entire Reproducible Code

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Conv2DTranspose
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, Activation, Reshape, LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from numpy import ones
from numpy import zeros
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy.random import randn
from numpy import vstack
from numpy import array
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from matplotlib import pyplot


def load_data(filepath):
    image_array = []
    n = 0
    for fold in os.listdir(filepath):
      if fold != 'wiki.mat':
        if n > 1:
            break
        for img in os.listdir(os.path.join(filepath, fold)):
            image = load_img(filepath + fold +  '/'+ img, target_size=(64, 64))
            img_array = img_to_array(image)
            img_array = img_array.astype('float32')
            img_array = img_array / 255.0
            image_array.append(img_array)
        n += 1
    return array(image_array)
def generate_latent_points(n_samples, latent_dim=100):
    latent_points = randn(n_samples * latent_dim)
    latent_points = latent_points.reshape(n_samples, latent_dim)
    return latent_points

def generate_real_samples(n_samples, dataset):
    ix = randint(0, dataset.shape[0], n_samples)
    x = dataset[ix]
    y = ones((n_samples, 1))
    return x, y

def generate_fake_samples(g_model, n_samples):
    latent_points = generate_latent_points(n_samples)
    x = g_model.predict(latent_points)
    y = zeros((n_samples, 1))
    return x, y

def save_plot(examples, epoch, n=10):
    # plot images
    for i in range(n * n):
        # define subplot
        pyplot.subplot(n, n, 1 + i)
        # turn off axis
        pyplot.axis('off')
        # plot raw pixel data
    pyplot.imshow(examples[i, :, :, 0])
    # save plot to file
    filename = 'generated_plot_e%03d.png' % (epoch+1)
    pyplot.savefig(filename)
    pyplot.close()

def summarize_performance(d_model, g_model, gan_model, dataset, epoch, n_samples=100):
    real_x, real_y = generate_real_samples(n_samples, dataset)
    _, d_real_acc = d_model.evaluate(real_x, real_y)
    fake_x, fake_y = generate_fake_samples(g_model, n_samples)
    _, d_fake_acc = d_model.evaluate(fake_x, fake_y)

    latent_points, y = generate_latent_points(n_samples), ones((n_samples, 1))
    gan_loss = gan_model.evaluate(latent_points, y)

    print('Epoch %d, acc_real=%.3d, acc_fake=%.3f, gan_loss=%.3f' % (epoch, d_real_acc, d_fake_acc, gan_loss))

save_plot(fake_x, epoch)
filename = 'Genarator_Model % d' % (epoch + 1)
g_model.save(filename)

def train(d_model, g_model, gan_model, dataset, epochs=200):
    batch_size = 64
    half_batch = int(batch_size / 2)
    batch_per_epoch = int(dataset.shape[0] / batch_size)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i in range(batch_per_epoch):
            real_x, real_y = generate_real_samples(half_batch, dataset)
            _, d_real_acc = d_model.train_on_batch(real_x, real_y)
            fake_x, fake_y = generate_fake_samples(g_model, half_batch)
            _, d_fake_acc = d_model.train_on_batch(fake_x, fake_y)

            latent_points, y = generate_latent_points(batch_size), ones((batch_size, 1))
            gan_loss = gan_model.train_on_batch(latent_points, y)

            print('Epoch %d, acc_real=%.3d, acc_fake=%.3f, gan_loss=%.3f' % (epoch, d_real_acc, d_fake_acc, gan_loss))
        if (epoch % 2) == 0:
            summarize_performance(d_model, g_model, gan_model, dataset, epoch)

dataset = load_data(filepath) # filepath is not defined since every person will have seperate filepath

discriminator_model = define_discriminator()
generator_model = define_generator()
gan_model = define_gan(discriminator_model, generator_model)

train(discriminator_model, generator_model, gan_model, dataset)
```

### Dataset

If you want [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tKx6egPVafsGgbCk7yKtaIcz_-8NMFTM?usp=sharing) is the dataset.